# React: How to do handleChange and handleSubmit for dynamically adding Input Textboxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a list. Each item in the list is having a textbox. Textbox is showing DisplayOrder. Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-butterfly-4tg2w0

In Post API call, how to pass changed textbox values with corresponding description-id as a collection. StoredProcedure is taking description-id and display-sequence as parameters to save changed data in the database.

Please help on form submit how to do this? Thanks

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import XMLParser from "react-xml-parser";

const data = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Category>
<description description-id="11" display-sequence="2">testing</description>
<description description-id="15" display-sequence="5">Guide</description>
<description description-id="20" display-sequence="7">test</description>
<description description-id="25" display-sequence="10">Guide</description>
<description description-id="30" display-sequence="12">test</description>
</Category>
</xml>`;

const REQUEST_URL = "";

const axios = {
  get: () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000, { data });
    })
};

class Sort_Descr extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      proddescriptions: [],
      proddescription_id: "",
      display_sequence: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getlistofdescriptions();
  }

  getlistofdescriptions() {
    axios
      .get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
      .then((response) => {
        const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
        const descriptions = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName(
          "description"
        );
        console.log(descriptions);
        this.setState({
          proddescriptions: jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("description")
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
              {this.state.proddescriptions.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={item.attributes["description-id"]}>
                    {item.attributes["description-id"]}
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      size="5"
                      maxlength="3"
                      value={item.attributes["display-sequence"]}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    &nbsp; {item.value}
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Sort list by updating the number in the textbox</h4>

      <Sort_Descr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `handleChange(event) {}`  you don't see a problem here? See [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing and updating JSON/XML data in state I'd suggest mapping it to a simpler object that is easier to identify and update. React state should be the *minimal* amount of data necessary to represent your information, store only what you need.

```
const proddescriptions = descriptions.map(({ attributes, value }) => ({
  id: attributes["description-id"],
  sequence: attributes["display-sequence"],
  value
}));
this.setState({ proddescriptions });
```

When mapping the `state.proddescriptions` to the inputs, use the `id` as the inputs `name` attribute value for identification when updating.

```
{this.state.proddescriptions.map((item) => (
  <li key={item.id}>
    <label>
      {item.id}
      <input
        type="text"
        name={item.id} // <-- name attribute
        size="5"
        maxLength="3"
        value={item.sequence}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </label>
    &nbsp; {item.value}
  </li>
))}
```

Implement the `handleChange` to shallow copy the previous state and update the matching array element by id.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    proddescriptions: prevState.proddescriptions.map((el) =>
      el.id === name
        ? {
            ...el,
            sequence: value
          }
        : el
    )
  }));
};
```

In the `handleSubmit` callback use the `onSubmit` event object to prevent the default form action and access the current `state.proddescriptions` and map it back to any format your APIs are expecting.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.proddescriptions);
  // manipulate `state.proddescriptions` into a request payload
};
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-do-handlechange-and-handlesubmit-for-dynamically-adding-input-text]

[image]

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for the help. Do we need to submit the complete object in post api or only the changed textbox values. Also, is there a way to refresh the list order on form submit without complete page refresh. thanks a lot.

Comment: @TestUser That depends entirely on what *that* specific endpoint needs to have passed to it. If the POST request needs that data massaged back into an object using the `"description-id"` and `"display-sequence"` keys then that's where you'd do it. Is there a way to refresh... the `this.state.proddescriptions` array/list when submitting the form data? What do you need to refresh?

Comment: Textbox values shows the sort order of the item. on form submit item will refresh and will display in the sort order.

Comment: @TestUser I'm not quite following that comment, but generally you could (a) optimistically update the local state with the "delta" of what you are POSTing and undo that state update if the POST fails, (b) do the POST and wait for it to succeed and update the local state with the "delta", (c) update the endpoint to return ***all*** of the new remote state, do the POST and replace the local state with the response value, (d) do the POST and wait for it to succeed and trigger a GET to get all the latest data.