# React: Checkboxlist SelectAll and ClearAll buttons not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying data in the checkboxlist. I have implemented Select All and ClearAll buttons that selects all or unselect all checkboxes.

Please find my react code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pond-07qnue

Please fix my code why SelectAll and ClearAll functionality is not working.

```
import React from "react";
const data = [
  { templateID: "11", templateName: "All" },
  { templateID: "21", templateName: "SC" }
];
export class Delete_Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Template_ID: "",
      TemplateName: "",
      Templatelist: [],
      checkedItems: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSelectAll = this.handleSelectAll.bind(this);
    this.handleClearAll = this.handleClearAll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTemplateList();
  }

  getTemplateList() {
    this.setState({
      Templatelist: data,
      TemplateName: data[0].templateName,
      loading: false
    });
    console.log(this.state.Templatelist);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
    const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
    const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
    if (index !== -1) {
      updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      updatedArray.push(id);
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: updatedArray
    }));
    console.log(this.state.checkedItems);
  }

  handleSelectAll() {
    return this.setState({
      checkedItems: this.state.Templatelist.map((id) => id)
    });
  }
  handleClearAll() {
    return this.setState({ checkedItems: [] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
          {this.state.Templatelist.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={item.templateID}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={item.templateID}
                  value={item.templateName}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                &nbsp; {item.templateName}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input
          type="button"
          name="SelectAll"
          value="Select All"
          onClick={this.handleSelectAll}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          name="UnSelectAll"
          value="Clear All"
          onClick={this.handleClearAll}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Delete_Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `checked` property to your checkbox based on what you have selected `this.state.checkedItems`. Also in `handleChange` method you convert it to an integer and stored while in `handleSelectAll` method you use the full object. So need to make sure to store at the same type.

```
import React from "react";
const data = [
  { templateID: "11", templateName: "All" },
  { templateID: "21", templateName: "SC" }
];
export class Delete_Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Template_ID: "",
      TemplateName: "",
      Templatelist: [],
      checkedItems: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSelectAll = this.handleSelectAll.bind(this);
    this.handleClearAll = this.handleClearAll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTemplateList();
  }

  getTemplateList() {
    this.setState({
      Templatelist: data,
      TemplateName: data[0].templateName,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
    const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
    if (index !== -1) {
      updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      updatedArray.push(id);
    }
    this.setState({
      checkedItems: updatedArray
    });
  }

  handleSelectAll() {
    this.setState({
      checkedItems: this.state.Templatelist.map((id) => id.templateID)
    });
  }
  handleClearAll() {
    this.setState({ checkedItems: [] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
          {this.state.Templatelist.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={item.templateID}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={item.templateID}
                  value={item.templateName}
                  checked={this.state.checkedItems.some(
                    (i) => i === item.templateID
                  )}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                &nbsp; {item.templateName}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input
          type="button"
          name="SelectAll"
          value="Select All"
          onClick={this.handleSelectAll}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          name="UnSelectAll"
          value="Clear All"
          onClick={this.handleClearAll}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Delete_Item;
```

Sample working at https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-darkness-l2vx52

Comment: Thanks Dhaval. It works great. please let me know how to close this question.

Comment: Dhawal, I need help in another question. Please find the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74229273/react-textboxes-not-able-to-edit-and-how-to-submit-data-as-an-array. Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks a lot.